# How can I query ASE Sybase database to get all users with creation date and assigned roles?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

Can someone please help me to get list of all users, created date and assigned roles to users in Sybase database? I tried all ways but no luck.

Thank you.

I tried to find in syslogins and sp_display but I am unable to find user created date.

Comment: please update the question with some of the queries you've tried; also consider updating the question to show some samples of the expected output (eg, what should the output for the `sa` account look like?)

Comment: also, please update the question with a clarification ... are you looking for (dataserver) login name or the (database) user name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all do you have the appropriate privs ? 
  To query the `syslogins table in the master database,` you need to have the `sso_role` or `sa_role` system role. To query the `sysusers` and `sysroles` tables in each individual database, you need to have the `sa_role` system role or be the owner of the database.

  ```
    EXEC sp_displaylogin
  ```

displays information about your login account, including the roles that are granted to you. If you have the sso_role or sa_role system roles, they will be listed

- Assuming your good on the above :

`syslogins` table is located in the `master` database, while the `sysusers` and `sysroles` tables are located in each individual database. You can join the `syslogins` table with the `sysusers` and `sysroles` tables to get a list of all users, their creation date, and assigned roles.

```
SELECT l.name AS 'User Name', l.createdate AS 'Creation Date', r.name AS 'Role Name'
FROM master..syslogins l
JOIN sysusers u ON l.suid = u.suid
JOIN sysroles r ON u.uid = r.lrid
WHERE u.uid > 2
```

Above is for users in the current database. If you want to retrieve this information for users in a different database, you need to run the query in that database.

In `ASE Sybase` ( Unlike Oracle or Teradata  ) it is not possible to write a single query that retrieves a list of all users, their creation date, and assigned `roles` across all databases. The `sysusers` and `sysroles` tables are located in each individual database and contain information about users and roles specific to that database. To get a list of all users, their creation date, and assigned roles across all databases, you would need to run separate queries in each database and combine the results programmatically using a `Stored Proc`